# Windows 7 crashes and freezes randomly

Tags: windows-7, freeze, crash, bsod, reboot

First of all, thanks for your time!

My problem is that PC freezing or craches randomly.
Sometimes crashes with BSOD, sometimes PC just reboots.
For notice, simple reboots are more frequent than BSOD cases

**All that happens:**

- when i play FIFA 14 (most frequently). I don't play other games, so can't compare frequency of crashes
- when i surfing the internet
- when i do basic staff (simple operations with files, typing)
- when i do nothing !)

**What i tried:**

- changed thermal paste for PCU
- checked HDD for bad sectors (its acceptably)
- updated all drivers with DriverMax
- reinstalled OS

Nothing of above was helpful

The summary PC specs:

- **OS**: Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit SP1
- **CPU**: Intel Core i5 2300 @ 2.80GHz (Sandy Bridge). Avg temp 46 °C
- **RAM**: 4.00GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 668MHz (9-9-9-24)
- **Motherboard**: ASUSTeK Computer INC. P8H67-M EVO (LGA1155). Avg temp 31 °C
- **Monitor**: W2486 (1920x1080@59Hz)
- **Graphic card**: 1024MB ATI Radeon HD 4800 Series (Gigabyte). Avg temp 45 °C
- **Storage**: 931GB Seagate ST31000528AS ATA Device (SATA). Avg temp 34 °C

**WhoCrashed** all the time shows errors with the same cause:

On Sat 9/17/2014 9:46:05 AM GMT your computer crashed
crash dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\091714-24382-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: **ntoskrnl.exe (nt+0x74540)** 
**Bugcheck code: 0x124 (0x0, 0xFFFFFA8005092028, 0xB2000000, 0x100402)**
Error: **WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR**
file path: **C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe**
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
company: Microsoft Corporation
description: NT Kernel & System
Bug check description: This bug check indicates that a fatal hardware error has occurred.
 This bug check uses the error data that is provided by the Windows Hardware Error Architecture (WHEA).
This is likely to be caused by a hardware problem problem. This problem might be caused by a thermal issue. 
The crash took place in the Windows kernel. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver that cannot be identified at this time.

What can be the problem?

**SOLVED** by updated BIOS to the latest version with ASUS AI Suite 2.
**Notice**: it would be safer to update step by step (version by version)

Comment: when was the last time you re-installed windows?

Comment: is doesn't matter, the crashes were right after reinstalling

Comment: 0x124 is fatal hardware error. Share the dump **C:\Windows\Minidump\091714-24382-01.dmp** so that I can see more details.

Comment: where is the dmp file?

Comment: sorry, i wasn't at home these days. The latest dump is here http://speedy.sh/xvVT8/092114-23946-01.dmp . Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get an `Internal unclassified` hardware error:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: fffffa8004fdc028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 00000000b2000000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 0000000000100402, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:
------------------


BUGCHECK_STR:  0x124_GenuineIntel

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN7_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  f

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17237 (debuggers(dbg).140716-0327) amd64fre

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_MAE

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_MAE

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:x64_0x124_genuineintel_processor_mae


2: kd> !errrec fffffa8004fdc028
===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ fffffa8004fdc028
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01cfd57f8cc18f63
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 9/21/2014 14:16:46 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa8004fdc0a8
Section       @ fffffa8004fdc180
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : Micro-Architectural Error
Flags         : 0x00
CPU Version   : 0x00000000000206a7
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000004

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa8004fdc0f0
Section       @ fffffa8004fdc240
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000004
CPU Id        : a7 06 02 00 00 08 10 04 - bf e3 9a 1f ff fb eb bf
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ fffffa8004fdc240

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ fffffa8004fdc138
Section       @ fffffa8004fdc2c0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : Internal unclassified (Proc 2 Bank 4)
  Status      : 0xb200000000100402

2: kd> !sysinfo machineid
Machine ID Information [From Smbios 2.6, DMIVersion 38, Size=3598]
BiosMajorRelease = 4
BiosMinorRelease = 6
BiosVendor = American Megatrends Inc.
BiosVersion = 1502
BiosReleaseDate = 03/02/2011
SystemManufacturer = System manufacturer
SystemProductName = System Product Name
SystemFamily = To be filled by O.E.M.
SystemVersion = System Version
SystemSKU = To be filled by O.E.M.
BaseBoardManufacturer = ASUSTeK Computer INC.
BaseBoardProduct = P8H67-M EVO
BaseBoardVersion = Rev 1.xx
2: kd> !sysinfo cpuinfo
[CPU Information]
~MHz = REG_DWORD 2809
Component Information = REG_BINARY 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Configuration Data = REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Identifier = REG_SZ Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7
ProcessorNameString = REG_SZ Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2300 CPU @ 2.80GHz
Update Signature = REG_BINARY 0,0,0,0,14,0,0,0
Update Status = REG_DWORD 2
VendorIdentifier = REG_SZ GenuineIntel
MSR8B = REG_QWORD 1400000000
2: kd> !sysinfo cpuspeed
CPUID:        "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2300 CPU @ 2.80GHz"
MaxSpeed:     2800
CurrentSpeed: 2809
```

I can see that the BIOS is a bit outdated. Flash the [BIOS 3703 which improves system stability.](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P8H67M_EVO/HelpDesk_Download/)

Comment: I updated BIOS to the latest (version by version) with ASUS AI Suite 2. And problem has gone. Thanks man :)

Comment: nice to hear this :)